# ReorderableListView and sqflite, best way to update database when reorder is called?

Tags: flutter, sqflite, flutter-listview, flutter-state

I want to save the state of my reordered list of items in the database so that when I reload or comeback to the list it will show the reordered one not the old state that is saved in the database.